# Java VNC Applet vs Screen Capture

Tags: java, video-capture, vnc

I am trying to make an application in which one component captures the screen of the user (for screen casting). I am aware that there are two options to achieve the same using a Java applet (please correct me if I am wrong). First is to use the java applet to take screen shots continuously and convert it into a video and upload it as a video file. And second is to create a java vnc server and record it as a .fbs file and play it using a player like: http://www.wizhelp.com/flashlight-vnc/index.html

I would like to know the best solution in terms of video quality, file size, cross-platform compatibility (windows and mac), firewall problems and finally ease of implementation.

I am very new to Java. Please tell me whats the best solution for my problem. Also, is it easy enough for me to program it on my own or should I get it developed via a freelancer. I have tons of programming experience (5+ years in LAMP) but none in Java.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think is THAT straight forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that this is pretty hard.  I implemented those two solutions (VNC and onboard screen capture) plus a third (capture from an external VGA source via an [Epiphan](http://www.epiphan.com/products/frame-grabbers/) grabber) for a former employer.  I had the best bandwidth-to-quality ratio with VNC, but I got higher framerate with VGA capture.  In all three cases, I reduced the frames + capture times to PNGs and sequenced them in a QuickTime reference movie.  Then I made flattened video (MPEG4 or SWF) of the results.  In my case, I then synchronized the screen video with a DV stream.

In the end the technology worked (see [a sample](http://www.media-landscape.com/yapc/2006-06-26.ChrisDolan/) of the output) but our business model failed.

Comment: @Chris Dolan "see a sample of the output" -- This domain has expired.

Comment: @MikeNereson -- thanks for pointing that out.  They're my former employer and I've passed on the message.  I think it was accidental.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, the older versions of applet had security restrictions that may not allow for screen capture. Instead, a java application may be feasible.
Regarding the build-it-yourself vs the fire-a-coder, it depends on how you value your time compared to what you can find on a freelancer site.
I think you can find someone from India/Romania/Poland/Other countries that can make it for an affordable price

Answer (score 1):

Given your Java knowledge and the difficulty of the task, have you considered taking an alternative approach?  For example, how about a native VNC server for the end-user, which  is just a small download and then they click "Run."  And that native server is programmed to capture the screen and send it straight to your web server, which has a client like vnc2swf or other means of converting the VNC stream to a video or .fbs file?  Does all that make sense?

Admittedly, without Java, you have to prepare one executable program per platform you want to support, however, I don't know.  That still sounds easier to me.  Consider Copilot.com.  They are doing VNC but they still use small native apps for each platform.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this seems the kind of job that requires a lot of experience. Even if you find code snippets all around the net to fix this and that, the overall result may be way worse than simply hiring an experienced Java programmer.